# SQL Update Trigger - Status Update

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to create an update trigger that will check if a status column value has changed e.g from Pending(10) to Live(13). This will update a `LiveDate` column to `GETDATE()`. But when the status changes again from Live to the next status in a process(ie a status not equal to 13), it will set LiveDate to null.

E.g Pending -> Live(LiveDate set correctly) -> Closed(LiveDate set to null).

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_livedate]
    ON [DB].[dbo].[Table1]

    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
        UPDATE dbo.Table1
        SET LiveDate = GETDATE()
        FROM dbo.Table1 T
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON T.Id = I.Id
        INNER JOIN DELETED D ON T.Id = D.Id
    WHERE I.StateID = 13 AND D.LiveDate IS NULL
```

I have tried the null check on the end to see if `LiveDate` has already been set but still no joy.

Comment: In order to know if a column was updates you can compare the DELETED table to the INSERTED table

Comment: I thought I understood your question but I'm re-reading it and not quite following by what you mean by "it will set LiveDate to null." - nothing in this trigger will do that. Is that *desired* behaviour to be added to the trigger? If not, look for another trigger or something else setting it `NULL`.

Comment: I'm still not clear from your description whether you're describing *what is happening currently* or *what you **want** to happen*.

Comment: apologies, this is happening currently. I don't want it to turn to null. When status goes from 13 to 14, live date shouldn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check a specific *transition*, use the `deleted` table also:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_livedate]
ON [DB].[dbo].[Table1]

AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.Table1
    SET LiveDate = GETDATE()
    FROM dbo.Table1 T
    INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON T.Id = I.Id
    INNER JOIN DELETED D ON T.Id = D.Id
    WHERE I.StateID = 13 AND D.StateID = 10
```

If what you were trying to express in your question is that "once `LiveDate` is set, it should not become unset", then make your `SET` line:

```
    SET LiveDate = COALESCE(LiveDate,GETDATE())
```

(But this will not prevent *other* actions from setting `LiveDate` to `NULL` if they're not covered by this trigger)

Comment: thanks for the advice on deleted table. I have updated my question to be clearer. I have given what you suggested a go. When the status changes from 13 to the next statusID, 14 for example, it still sets LiveDate to null. I want to store LiveDate only when statusId = 13, if its not 13, don't update the column.

Comment: @notoriousmonkey - as I tried to indicate in a comment on the question, if *something* is setting `LiveDate` to `null` and you don't want it to, that *something* is not *this* trigger (either variant, in question or my answer)

Comment: yes, you were right. something else is updating LiveDate, I'm using MVC EF and this went completely over my head. Cheers for making me think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DELETED` table also, in order to check the updated values.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_livedate] ON [DB].[dbo].[Table1]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
UPDATE dbo.Table1
SET LiveDate = GETDATE()
FROM dbo.Table1 Tab
JOIN INSERTED Ins ON Tab.ID = Ins.ID
JOIN DELETED Del ON Tab.ID = Del.ID
WHERE Ins.StateID = 13
    AND Del.StateID = 10
```